# One sign in for Apple ID across all applications on MacBook

Tags: apple-id

It seems like every built-in application on a MacBook has a separate Apple ID log in. Is there a way to log in to your Apple account in one place on your MacBook Pro and have it sign in your iTunes, Messages, and other applications that have an Apple ID automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the case then that is how you've set it up. If you want to use a single Apple ID, log out of all of the accounts, then log back in to each with a single Apple ID.